# I am stuck on level 7 :Removing x's from the sentence

Tags: vim-adventures

I am stuck on a puzzle on level 7 where the player needs to remove the x's from the sentence.

`fx will find forward, 
t will go txill,
; wixll repeat them,
, rexverse the dexal "`

I only have 12 key presses to pass, but I never can complete it. I get to the last step when I have 0 chances left. I believe in this exercise I should use 't\T\f\F'  and ';' and ',' buttons, however I am still stuck.[image: Level 7 part 2.5]

Comment: did you manage to solve it? What were the precise strokes you used?

Answer (score 8):

Searches made using `f` and `t` are remembered across different blocks of text in the game (and across buffers in vim), so you can use  `;` and `,` on the first line using the saved search from your previous attempt to save one keystroke.

Comment: can you give the exact sequence of keyboard strokes? I am still missing one and Im already using `;` and `,`

Comment: Very tricky that this requires you to enter the command before getting on the text board so that it is already in your saved searches.

Answer (score 4):

In order to finish this puzzle, you need to collect the <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> keys. Note that when you bump into bushes, you sometimes find things - either keyboard shortcuts or people.

You should go back to the Alice text at the beginning of the level (the long one) and go through all the bushes. There are a lot of things to find. It will also make traversing the text a lot easier.

One more thing, if you're still missing one keystroke to finish this text after you collect everything, remember that <kbd>;</kbd> and <kbd>,</kbd> repeat the last search within the line, even if it was not performed on the current text.

Comment: can you give the exact sequence of keyboard strokes? I am still missing one and Im already using `;` and `,`

Answer (score 0):

As said above; using ft,; but....  you cannot complete the puzzle on the first attempt.

Comment: Can you go into more detail please? Why can't they beat the puzzle on the first attempt?

Comment: can you give the exact sequence of keyboard strokes? I am still missing one and Im already using `;` and `,`

Answer (score 0):

Since a list of the precise keystrokes is requested, I've just confirmed this works.  Spoilers below.

This puzzle can be done with two passes.  First pass:

`j` to enter the puzzle; `0` to get to the beginning of the first line; `fx` to search for **x**, which stores it in the search memory.  Now press `[esc]` twice to quit the first pass.

Second pass:

1. `j` to enter the puzzle;
2. `,` to search backwards for the **x**, then `x` to delete it;
3. `j` down to second line;
4. `;` to repeat the search forwards for **x**, then `x` to delete it;
5. `j` down to third line;
6. `,` to repeat the search backwards for **x**, then `x` to delete it;
7. `j` down to fourth line, already on the **x** so `x` to delete it;
8. finally, `;` to repeat the search forwards for **x**, and `x` to delete it.

Happy Vim Adventuring!